# Can I add string of text with a date attached all in one field?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a macro that does a few things to my PDF documents. Currently I can add a text field where the macro then places the current date. I would like to add a string of text in front of the date. Something like `MACRO Date: 05/03/2017`

I have tried adding a string of text next to the `AcDateFormat` this did not work. I have also tried to add the string of text in the same quote with mm/dd/yyyy" that kind of worked, but has change some of the letters to numbers resulting in something like this `28ACRO Daae: 05/03/2017` on the page.

Is there a way to add the text to the field then add the date next to the text?

I do not want to add two separate fields, because I need to be able to search for the term `MACRO Date:` and then have the text after return.

This is the working code I have. Can anyone shed some light on how to add a string of text next to the date as it prints into the field?

```
var AcDate = new Date();var AcDateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages;p++) {
    var fd = this.addField("xftDate", "text", 0, [10, 10, 100, 25]);
    fd.value =  util.printd(AcDateFormat, AcDate);
    fd.textSize = 16;
    fd.readonly = true;
    fd.alignment = "right";
}
```

Comment: " ..I need to be able to search for the term MACRO Date: and then have the text after return." If you want to do it by code then using "MACRO_Date:" (= one word) will be much more simple. Take it as hint.

Comment: @ReFran Your answer does the job. The main goal was to have a time stamp on the PDF file with `"MACRO Date: (Insert Date)"` and the answer you gave does that. I can just write a regex tag function that will search for the MACRO Date and return what comes after to a variable for the rest of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fd.value = "myDate:" + util.printd(AcDateFormat, AcDate) + " that's it";